# Find the horizontal asymptotes of $f(x) = \frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert^3+1}$

Tags: calculus

Taken from Thomas' Calculus 12e
Find the horizontal asymptote of the graph of:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert^3+1}$$

Solution: We calculate the limits as ${x \to \pm \infty}$

For $x\ge0$: $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert ^3+1} =\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{x^3+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-(2/x^3)}{1+(1/x^3)}=1$$

I understand all except why the answer is one. I actually cannot find out how to get the answer.

Comment: they factored out $x^3$, and the terms $\frac{-2}{x^3}$ and $\frac{1}{x^3}$ tend to $0$ as $x$ tend to $\infty$..

Comment: @Jinzu  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

As you find out, the limit as $x\to \infty$ is $1$ then $y=1$ is an horizontal asymptote.

For $x\to -\infty$ we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert ^3+1} =\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{-x^3+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1-(2/x^3)}{-1+(1/x^3)}=-1$$

then $y=-1$ is an horizontal asymptote for $x\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Turning your second expression into your third isn't always too helpful for calculating the limit. In general, when you have the expression 
$$
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of the same degree, this limit is the ratio of the leading coefficients. In your example, this is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I always tell my students to not divide anything and look at the powers.

If the highest power in the denominator is larger than that of the numerator, the limit at infinity is zero. If the highest power in the denominator is equal to that of the numerator, the limit at infinity is the ratio of the coefficients of those highest powers.

Here, the limiting behavior is $\frac{x^3}{|x|^3}$. The coefficients are $1$, so the limit is $1$.

Comment: Doesn't the idea come from the factorization and cancelling terms? (I'm just a student so i'm curious too :D).

Comment: But that's just giving your students a canned, rote formula for an answer, rather than expecting them to understand and derive it. Not my style of teaching.

Comment: The long answer involves comparing growth of polynomials. I also tell them that.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the function's domain is $\mathbb R$ except where $f$ is not defined namely $x=-1$.

Now if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$, then $y=a$ is a horizontal asymptote.

Similarly, if $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = b$, for some $b \in \mathbb R$, then $y=b$ is a horizontal asymptote.

For $x\to\infty$, we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert ^3+1} =\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{x^3+1}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3/x^3-(2/x^3)}{x^3/x^3+(1/x^3)}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-(2/x^3)}{1+(1/x^3)}$$

$$=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} [1-(2/x^3)]}{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} [1+(1/x^3)]}=\frac{ [\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}1-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(2/x^3)]}{ [\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}1+\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1/x^3)]}$$

$$=\frac{ [1-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(2/x^3)]}{ [1+\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1/x^3)]} = \frac{ [1-0]}{ [1+0]} = \frac11 = 1$$

Thus, $y=1$ is a vertical asymptote

Similarly, for $x\to-\infty$, we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{\lvert x\rvert ^3+1} =\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{(-x)^3+1}$$

$$= \cdots$$

$$= \cdots$$

$$= \frac{ [1-\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(2/x^3)]}{ [-1+\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(1/x^3)]} = \frac{ [1-0]}{ [-1+0]} = \frac1{-1} = -1$$

Thus, $y=-1$ is a vertical asymptote

Soooo...do you know why

$$0 = \lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(2/x^3) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(2/x^3) = \lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(1/x^3) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1/x^3)$$

?